# Categorization of variables based on selection process response

Tags: clustering, biostatistics, trend, bioinformatics, sequence-analysis

**EDIT:** Following a discussion on Meta, I will try to clarify this question more, hopefully giving more context which should help solve some of the issues.

I have 12 observations for several hundred thousand variables, e.g. a table with dimensions 300K x 12, coming from an sequencing project. In this context the rows correspond to sequences and columns correspond to samples that were analyzed. The samples, on the other hand, correspond to a number of different processes which were applied to an original biological sample. Here's a graphical representation:

[image]

The processes are expected to favor some sequences, thus increasing levels of the same process should *in theory* enrich (i.e. increase in abundance) some sequences while eliminating others. **The goal** is to be able to pick up sequences that are favored by each individual process, but not by others.

I'd like to automate this categorization since:

1. The exact setup of the experiments do vary, thus the solution needs to be as general as possible
2. It would be more exciting to have a known method to rely on, instead of *ad hoc* analysis of the numbers.

If I plot the abundance matrix in R, I can visualize the values as what I refer to "trends". (Please ignore the x-axis label here)

[image]

That figure alone isn't very useful however since the absolute abundance/copy number may be misleading as the total number of sequences per sample is not fixed. Also any classification efforts using k-means/medians or DBSCAN on absolute quantities have not been fruitful.

Another way to visualize would be to scale/normalize each value by the column sums and plot the relative representation of each sequence within the sample, which yields the following graph for the first 100 sequences:

[image]

Here the samples 1-3 correspond to the branch of process I, 4-6 correspond to process II, 7-8 to process IV, 9-11 to process III, and sample 12 is the control/untreated sample. Of noteworthy here are the "spikes" around certain samples:

- 3: corresponding to sequences enriched by process I,
- 6: corresponding to sequences enriched by process II,
- 8: corresponding to sequences enriched by process IV,
- 11:corresponding to sequences enriched by process III,
- as well as sudden increases at 12, corresponding to sequences that exists plenty in the untreated sample but are at selective disadvantage with respect to the process I-IV.

Given more detail on the origin and structure of the data, my question is if there are methods which I can use to effectively categorize sequences based on their response to the different processes? **It's important that the solution is generally applicable however, since not all projects have the exact same setup.**

I am inclined to think that I will need to devise an algorithm from scratch for this specific scenario, but I just wanted to make sure that there isn't anything out there already. I am working with Python for data processing, and R for analysis. Suggestions?

Comment: @PeterFlom seriously?! not a comment, not a single word on what is unclear? How trigger happy are you?

Comment: Yeah I think this is clear enough as is. I'd say fit a regression model of the log of whatever is on the Y axis. Then cluster the regression coefficients. That will identify ones in which only respond to A and ones that only respond to B, etc.

Comment: Thanks! - those graphs are much easier to read. What are "copy number" & "sample"? And "x"?

Comment: @Scortchi I thought the images would be shown on original size when clicked, apparently that's not how it works. Sorry about that.. Copy number is the measurements we have. Samples are the different treatments $a_i$ to $c_3$. And $x$ refers to the control / untreated sample

Comment: It'd be helpful to include that info. in the question.